# Can I fit a RaceFace crankset with a SRAM bottom bracket (and how do I know)?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

I have a bike with a SRAM BB https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/bb-gxp-a1

I’d like to fit these cranks https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/race-face-ride-narrow-wide-10sp-mtb-chainset/rp-prod113370

How can I know if they will fit? Are there any other questions I have to ask before I can know for sure?

Comment: I’ve established that the bike has a BSA threaded BB

Comment: Actually it has a BSA threaded bottom bracket *shell*. There are several different bottom bracket types that will fit in that: square taper cartridge, Shimano HollowtechII, SRAM GXP etc

Answer (score 1):

There is no information I can find on the Chain Reaction Cycle page that indicates what bottom bracket standard the crank requires. Seems the crank was originally sold with a Race Face bottom bracket and that bottom bracket was heavily implied (through the product images) to fit an ISO/BSA threaded frame of either 68 or 73mm shell width.

I checked the Race Face website and cannot find a product that is obviously the same. At least a few of their cheaper cranks are specified as having a 24mm axle. That definitely will not fit in a SRAM GXP bottom bracket as those are 24mm on the drive side, 22mm on the non drive side.

If you *definitely* want this crank to fit, buy a Race Face BSA bottom bracket as well, that will fit your frame and the crank will fit the bottom bracket.

It looks like the the Race Face BSA bottom bracket is the same dimensions as a Shimano HollowTech II bottom bracket, so you could try one of those, but I cannot absolutely guarantee it will work (there may be some variation in total width).

Comment: Are there any general principles for deciding compatibility, or is it just (highly impressive) knowledge and experience?

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor you basically just have to know what all the bb standards are. Unfortunately there a lot of them and they are confusing. This is the best chart I’ve found https://wheelsmfg.com/bb-standards